# Is it possible to have App-distinct Color Scheme in ConEmu?

Tags: bash, cygwin, powershell, colors, conemu

I am presently using **Bash** (with Cygwin), as well as **Powershell**, both using **ConEmu**. I'm using bash.exe and powershell.exe via tasks. I'd like to use **different colour schemes** for the different applications. I'd imagine this has to be done somehow via the app-distinct part of settings.. However, I can't figure out exactly how, and couldn't find a solution to the problem. I'd also like to know what the colour palette override does, and how to use it. I want the end result to be so, such that the two windows can be opened together(along with their respective colours) in ConEmu by the use of Tasks.

P.S. I have configured and made a separate colour scheme for the Cygwin tab (console) of my ConEmu. I'd like to ask Maximus specifically for help, as well as anybody who could help me.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

As you said, in `Settings`, `Features`, `App distinct`, click on `+`, and input the executable name such as `vim.exe` (for multiple applications, use `|`, such as `vim.exe|nano.exe`. Then you can check `Color palette override` and choose the color scheme you want to apply for the application. In my case I had to restart ConEmu for it to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the names of the respective applications under Features > App Distinct and override the color palette. I'd post a screenshot but I don't have enough rep.